# Calling servlets from client side

Tags: java, servlets

I had been reading on servlets and all books deal with invoking a servlet by means of a form (POST requests).
I was wondering if there are other means to invoke a servlet by a client.

Here is my understanding: For POST requests to a servlet, we use a link thus making a GET request on that servlet and in the servlet we need to call doPost() from doGet().

Comment: I restate my question: What are the different ways to make a POST request (to a servlet) from client's page (say JSP or HTML page)?

Comment: Put your mouse above the `servlets` tag below the question until a box pops up, click the *info* link therein and then enlighten yourself.

Comment: @BalusC Never knew there's something so elaborate in _info_. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a client that creates `GET` and `POST` HTTP messages and invoke a servlet. However you can use the [Apache Commons HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to do that.

Also, from your question you seem to thin that **all** Servlets handle `GET` requests via a `POST` request. That is incorrect. The reason it is done in the servlet you viewed is because the servlet does that same thing for both `GET` and `POST` request. So to minimize the amount of duplicate code it is so written.

UPDATE: It seems [Apache Commons HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) is now end of life, and is no longer being developed. It has been replaced by the [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) project in its [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) and [HttpCore](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/) modules, which offer better performance and more flexibility.

UPDATE2: I took your original question as "How can we invoke servlets other than from the browser". Well, a browser is just a client that efficiently and easily lets us make `GET` and `POST` requests to a server [in our case a `Servlet`]. We can also write a Java proram to make `GET` and `POST` request to our `Servlet`, but that will be tedious and cumbersome. So, we can use the libraries specified above to do that. These libraries are not limited to client Java prorams and can be used from any application that can invoke Java code [and that includes JSP].

Comment: could you also list different ways to invoke a servlet from the browser?

Comment: From the browser? We do it everyday. Click on a link in any HTML page; if the server to which the link points to is a Java server, chances are that yu are invoking a servlet. ;-)

Comment: yes. So links is one way to invoke a servlet. Other ways that come to my mind is form submission where a user clicks a "submit" button. What are the other ways? Is it possible to call a servlet for other user events other than form submission say, a button click, selecting a radio button, or invoke automatically after a timer expires, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> For POST requests to a servlet, we use a link thus making a GET
>   request on that servlet

That doesn't make sense and is incorrect.

The client side either makes a [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GET_%28HTTP%29#Request_methods) or a [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request.  In an html form you specify which in the method attribute, and when using ajax/javascript you also specify which.

Yes, in the servlet you specify doGet and doPost.  The convention is to use POST to send(post) data to the server, while get is used to return data; however this does not *have* to be enforced.

Answer (score 1):

You may request a servlet using `java.net.UrlConnection` and `java.net.URL`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the servlet api (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html).

Four methods are supported (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).  You could theoretically use either one from the client side.

In reality however, your client side will usually be a browser or a webservice consumer. In reality, only GET and POST are used often.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Apache's [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) library. Really easy to use and customizable.
Here's some code for you to get started:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("YourServletURL");
List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
// Set your parameters here...
UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
request.setEntity(formEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
if (resEntity != null)
    // Here you can read the response
    EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 8 http 1.1 methods: GET, POST, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE and CONNECT. The servlet api only implements 7 of them with their corresponding matching doXXXX(): doGet(), doPost(),doOptions(), doHead(), doTrace(), doPut(), doDelete(). But for most servlet devopment you will use either doGet() (for simple request) or doPost() (to accept and process form data).

> Here is my understanding: For POST requests to a servlet, we use a link thus making a GET request on that servlet and in the servlet we need to call doPost() from doGet()

I do not understand this part but I think you are wrong. The service() method figures out which servlet method to call based on the HTTP method (e. g. GET, POST). If the client sent a HTTP GET request then the service() method calls the doGet() method, passing the request and response objects as arguments. For convenience some IDEs set up servlets so their doPost() method calls doGet() because they are intended to handle GET and POST requests identically.

Answer (score -1):

There are two was to call a servlet, HTTP GET which invokes doGet() and HTTP POST which invokes doPost(). The HTTP protocol is simple and numerous clients can be used. You can write your own, you can use readymade java libraries, you can use command line utilites like curl.

The doGet() and doPost() methods can do the same thing or different things.

There are two common ways of designing servlets:

1. Each servlet does the same in doGet() and doPost(), with one calling the other.

Example:
FindCustomerServlet - find customer records
UpdateCustomerServlet - update customer record

1. The servlet does different things in doGet() and doPost().

Example:
CustomerServlet - use GET to find records, POST to update.